# Telegram bot to filter certain words

Tags: java, python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to manage a supergroup on Telegram.
I'm wondering if there's a way to filter certain words (like curse words) through a bot?
If there is, I would much appreciate if you help me coding it.

Comment: As we are talking right now, there are like a thousand bots out there doing this. They sure can do this as an administrator in groups, and actually this wasn't my question.

Answer (score 0):

If your bot is the admin with the priviledge of deleting messages, it can remove any message it wants. 
Make sure that you have turned the group privacy of the bot off.